# docker "No such container" even though docker container list displays that container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am running two containers which I would like to communicate with each other via `localhost` (it's a web app and a cypress test container)

I got it all to work correctly locally (on a Mac), but when running same commands in Jenkins the cypress test container can not start due to not being able to find the web app container. Why is that ?

Here's the code

```
docker run --rm -d \
     -v ${current_dir}:/repo \
     -w ${current_dir}/${app_path} \
     --name myApp server start \
     --bind 127.0.0.1"

docker container ls # This display the list of containers, and my container is first in the list 

docker run --rm \
     -v ${volumeDir}:/e2e 
     -w /e2e --network container:myApp \
     -e CYPRESS_CW_DEPLOYMENT_NAME=${env.K8S_DEPLOYMENT_NAME} \
     --entrypoint=cypress cypress/included:8.7.0 run \
     --browser chrome
```

In Jenkins only, I get this error after the last docker command
`docker: Error response from daemon: No such container: myApp`

Comment: what does `--rm` option? ;) https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: Any reason you're not using compose? It's pretty much made for this sort of thing

Comment: I'd use normal container networking here -- `docker network create` a network, run both containers `docker run --net` that network, and use one container's `--name myapp` as a DNS name from the other.  What leads to trying to force the meaning of `localhost` here?

Comment: @DavidMaze I will try that. The localhost was mainly to minimize the number of params to pass to tests. I was trying to get it to work in any way I can, and got it all sorted out locally, but of course Jenkins running on ubuntu still not working.

Comment: @Phil tried with docker compose, but the issue is that my web app is starting from local code (not as Dockerfile ) , and so the port isn't exposed when the server starts since the container is already live. I need to expose the ports on a server after the container has started . May be there is a trick to get that working ?

Comment: A container only runs a single process, and I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to publish the port immediately (you could get "connection refused" errors if the process isn't actually accepting connections yet but that's the only real impact).